# Controlling Inputfields with radio buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, disabled-input

I have the following idea. My view contains 3 input fields and radio buttons which need to work each other.

Firstly when the view is displayed you can see the input fields only. If the user clicks on one of the input fields the other fields disabled and the radio buttons to this input fields are showing. If the user want to use an other input field of these three then he needs to click on one of the radio buttons then the other two input field will disabled.

Here is the currently code:

```
...
<input type="text" name="Id" ng-model="search.id" ng-click="disabled = !disabled" ng-disabled="..." />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="!disabled" />
...
<input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="search.name" ng-click="disabled = !disabled" ng-disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="!disabled" />
...
<input type="text" name="Age" ng-model="search.age" ng-click="disabled = !disabled" ng-disabled="disabled" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="!disabled" />
```

How can I realise that? Currently the first input field works.

Comment: you want the text input disabled or disappeared?

Answer (score 2):

Try to give a value to `disabled`

```
...
<input type="text" name="Id" ng-model="search.id" ng-click="disabled = 1" ng-disabled="disabled!=1" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="disabled==1" />
...
<input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="search.name" ng-click="disabled = 2" ng-disabled="disabled!=2" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="disabled==2" />
...
<input type="text" name="Age" ng-model="search.age" ng-click="disabled = 3" ng-disabled="disabled!=3" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="disabled==3" />
```

Answer (score 1):

this can certainly work, just make sure you are using different $scope variables for each control:

```
<input type="text" name="Id" ng-model="search.id" ng-click="disabledId = !disabledId" ng-disabled="disabledId" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-show="disabledId" ng-click="disabledName = true; disabledId=false; disabledAge=true"/>
...
<input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="search.name" ng-click="disabledName = !disabledName" ng-disabled="disabledName" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-show="disabledName" ng-click="disabledName = false; disabledId=true; disabledAge=true"/>
...
<input type="text" name="Age" ng-model="search.age" ng-click="disabledAge = !disabledAge" ng-disabled="disabledAge" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-show="disabledAge" ng-click="disabledAge=false; disabledId = true; disabledName=true"/>
```

While this should work here, I recommend not to put so much JS-code into the HTML, better would be to add a method on $scope like `$scope.radioClicked(buttonId)` and then call this method on ng-click.

Also using ng-show instead of ng-hide helps readability - no double negation.

Comment: Do you think a switch-statement would be useful?

Comment: Well,  does this solution work? If not,what is the problem?  Why are you asking about a switch statement- (sure,  you could use one, there are dozens of ways to do this)

Comment: Because I have edited my form and using a method called `disabled()`. Now the disabled-method send an item for each input field. In my example the numbers 1,2 and 3. In my Controller is the disabled()-method and the item will checked with a switch statement. `case 1: $scope.disabledId = false; $scope.disabledName = true; $scope.disabledAge = true; ...` and so on. Is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my input fields. It is a possible solution but only I need the interaction with radio buttons and the input fields.

```
<input type="text" name="Id" ng-model="search.id" ng-click="nameDis = !nameDis;ageDis = !ageDis" ng-disabled="idDis" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="!idDis" />
...
<input type="text" name="Name" ng-model="search.name" ng-click="idDis = !idDis;ageDis = !ageDis" ng-disabled="nameDis" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="!nameDis" />
...
<input type="text" name="Age" ng-model="search.age" ng-click="nameDis = !nameDis;idDis = !idDis" ng-disabled="ageDis" />
<input type="radio" class="radio" ng-hide="!ageDis" />
```